# Cleaning dynamic memory allocation in a call back function

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
My callback function looks like this.

```
void  cloud_cb (const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input_pc)
{
  // Convert the sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 data to pcl/PointCloud - Dataset
  pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloud_in(new pcl::PointCloud<PointT>);
  pcl::fromROSMsg(*input, *cloud_in);
  // pcl::norms
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
  ....
  ....
  for(auto searchPoint: filtered_cloud->points)
  {
    pcl::PCA<PointT> local_pca = new pcl::PCA<PointT>;
    pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers(new pcl::PointIndices());
    ....
    ....
   delete local_pca;
   delete inliers;
}
publisher(*cloud_normals);
// delete cloud;
// delete cloud_normals;
}
```

Is it a good practice to  de-allocate memory for the variables "cloud" , "cloud_normals" after the end of callback function ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287305/cleaning-dynamic-memory-allocation-in-a-call-back-function./) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2018-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The pcl Ptrs are boost shared_ptrs and clean up after themselves (you should look this up elsewhere, http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/common_2include_2pcl_2point__cloud_8h_source.html line 428 for example), but local_pca is raw allocated memory so you need to clean that up yourself after you finish using it (like the end of the callback) unless somewhere in the `...` you are handing it to a constructor or something else that takes ownership of the memory.

This isn't really ros related except you happen to be in a callback and converting to pcl from a sensor_msg, the memory allocation is purely the domain of pcl/boost/C++.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1